# My second hangman game (Hangman in C++), how to avoid nested while-loops? How to stick to the SRP?

Tags: c++, c++17, hangman

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237122/a-first-hangman-game-in-c/237139?noredirect=1#comment466136_237139) I already asked for tips, and I wrote another hangman game with the tips I got.

My questions are: is `int game()` doing too many things that I should split further into smaller functions?

And how to avoid those nested while-loops? Or are they ok for what I intend (to make it possible to replay the game without executing it more than once)?

The code:

```
/*
Name of the program:            Hangman
Purpose of the program:         This is a game.
Who wrote this code and when:   Jan Wollert, 20.02.2020
Version number:                 2.0
Assumed user input:             All lower case English characters
*/

#include <iostream>     // required for outputting text on screen and for reading the user's input
#include <string>       // needed for string operations
#include <fstream>      // needed for checking if file exists;
#include <random>       // needed for a (pseudo)random word each time
#include <streambuf>    // needed for loading a file to a string
#include <limits>       // used for the "Press Enter to continue"-message
#include<bits/stdc++.h> // needed for random word from a string
#include <utility>      // needed for a random word from a string

const std::string version_number = "V2.0";
const std::string screen_clear_string = std::string (50, '\n');

// self explanatory
void press_enter_to_continue()
{
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << std::flush;
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
}

// function that acts as a screen clear
void screen_clear()
{
    std::cout << screen_clear_string;
}

// function that checks if a file exists
bool fexists(std::string file_name)
{
    std::ifstream ifile(file_name);
    return (bool)ifile;
}

// function that loads a file to a string
std::string load_file_to_string(std::string file_name)
{
    std::string string_from_file="";
    if(fexists(file_name))
    {
        std::ifstream t(file_name);

        t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        string_from_file.reserve(t.tellg());
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        string_from_file.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    }
    else
    {
        string_from_file="1";
    }
    return string_from_file;
}

// choosing a random line from a string
std::string random_word_from_string(std::string input)
{
    static auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
    std::string random_word="";
    std::string word="";
    std::stringstream iss(input);
    auto count = 0u;
    while (iss >> word)
    {
        if (std::uniform_int_distribution{0u,count++}(gen) == 0)
        {
            random_word = word;
        }
    }
    return random_word;
}

// function for determining if a char is in a string
bool is_inside(const std::string & str, char c)
{
    return str.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}

// function for determining if a character is in the alphabet
bool is_alpha(char c)
{
    if (isalpha(c)==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// game function
int game()
{
    std::string dictionary=load_file_to_string("wordlist.txt");
    // check if the file opening has succeeded otherwise end the function
    if (dictionary=="1")
    {
        std::cout << "Please make sure that wordlist.txt is in the same directory as this program!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << screen_clear_string << "Welcome to Hangman "<< version_number << "!\n";
    press_enter_to_continue();
    screen_clear();

    // initializing variables
    char another_game='y';
    std::string secret_word="";
    std::string guessed_word="";
    std::string guessed_letters="";
    char letter=' ';
    int fails=0;

    // replay the game with a different word if you want, that's why the while-loop
    while (another_game=='y')
    {
        // making the state clean after a finished game
        secret_word=random_word_from_string(dictionary);
        guessed_word=std::string(secret_word.length(),'_');
        fails=0;
        guessed_letters="";

        // the actual game
        while(guessed_word!=secret_word && fails<10)
        {
            screen_clear();
            letter='_';
            std::cout << guessed_word << "\n";
            std::cout << "Guess a letter.\n";
            std::cout << "Already guessed letters: " << guessed_letters << " Remaining tries: " << 10-fails<< "\n";
            while (!isalpha(letter) || is_inside(guessed_letters, letter) )
            {
                std::cin >> letter;
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
            }
            if(is_inside(secret_word,letter))
            {
                for(unsigned int i=0; i<secret_word.length(); ++i)
                {
                    if (letter==secret_word.at(i))
                    {
                        guessed_word.at(i)=letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                guessed_letters+=letter;
                fails++;
            }
        }
        if(guessed_word==secret_word)
        {
            std::cout << "Congratulations, the word was indeed " << guessed_word << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, you lose, the word was " << secret_word << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Another game? (y/n)\n";
        std::cin >> another_game;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    game();
    return 0;
}
```

The wordlist.txt contains this words with this format:

```
wordone
wordtwo
wordthree
wordn
```

This is compiled with `-std=c++17`

Comment: _"And how to avoid those nested while-loops?"_ `goto` maybe? Well, that's a joke ;-) Why do you believe these are bad?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I read in a book that those generally produce troubles. BUT are neccessary sometimes, I just wonder if mine are neccessary or if it could be written better.

Comment: _"I read in a book that those generally produce troubles."_ That's nonsense. Nested loops aren't generally produce trobles. If these are needed, they are needed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah, ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Splitting up `game()`

> My questions are: is `int game()` doing too many things that I should split further into smaller functions?

You can definitely split up `game()` into more functions. There is no hard rule for when to split up a function. There are some rules of thumb, like if a function is more than one screen big or more than say 30 lines. However, the best way is to find blocks of code that are either very generic and could be reused elsewhere (you already do that with `press_enter_to_continue()` and `clear_screen()`), or blocks of code that can stand on their own. For example, most of the code inside the outer `while`-loop in `game()` deals with handling a single game of hangman. You could move it to its own function, so the `while`-loop is reduced to:

```
while (another_game == 'y')
{
    do_one_game();

    std::cout << "Another game? (y/n)\n";
    std::cin >> another_game;
}
```

This makes the function `game()` much smaller, and it is now much easier to see from a quick glance that it is repeating games until the user wants to stop.

Another great candidate for getting its own function is the inner-most `while`-loop. It basically reads characters until you enter a letter that hasn't already been guessed. You could create a function for it like so:

```
char get_guess(const std::string &guessed_letters)
{
    char letter;

    do {
        std::cin >> letter;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (!isalpha(letter) || is_inside(guessed_letters, letter));

    return letter;
}
```

You could also create a function for filling in a guessed letter at the right places in the `guessed_word` string.

## Avoiding nested loops

> And how to avoid those nested while-loops? Or are they ok for what I intend (to make it possible to replay the game without executing it more than once)?

There is nothing wrong with nesting loops. In many cases, it's the right thing to do. However, as shown above, in your case you can easily reduce one level of nesting by creating a function `do_one_game()` that contains all the code inside the outer loop,
and another one by creating `get_guess()`.

## Consider using `std::getline()` to read input

You are jumping through hoops to read single characters and then ignoring everything until a newline character. It might be simpler to use `[std::getline()`][1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline); this function reads a whole line into a `std::string`. For example, you could then write:

```
std::string guess;
std::getline(std::cin, guess);
letter = guess[0];
```

Note that if something happens to the input, `std::getline()` might return an empty string. It's always good to add some error checking to ensure you got valid input. With `std::getline()`, you can do it like so:

```
if (!std::getline(std::cin, guess))
{
   // handle error here
}
```

## Use C++17's `std::filesystem` if possible

C++17 introduced the [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) that makes it easier to perform operations on files and directories. In order to check if a file exists, you can use [`std::filesystem::exists(file_name)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

However, your function `fexists()` is not necessary at all. It opens a file, and if it succeeds you open it again. That is rather silly. Why not just unconditionally open the file in `load_file_to_string()`, and do the error checking there? It would look like:

```
std::ifstream t(file_name);

if (t.good())
{
   // read file here
}
```

Also note that checking whether a file exists is no guarantee that you can actually succesfully read the whole file. In general you should check that the state of the `std::ifstream` is still OK after reading the contents of the file.

## Don't write useless functions

You wrote `is_alpha()`, which just calls `isalpha(c)` and returns its result. You are not using this function at all, and even if you did, you could just have called `isalpha()` instead. You should remove this function.

## Use exceptions or explicit error codes to return errors from functions

Your function `load_file_to_string()` returns the string `"1"` if it couldn't find the file. However, you could actually create a file `wordlist.txt` that just contains the text `"1"`. You would still get the error message in this case, which would not be correct. Avoid situations like this where you can have confusion between valid and invalid return values.

Either use exceptions to return an error, like so:

```
#include <stdexcept>

std::string load_file_to_string(const std::string &filename)
{
    ...
    if (error)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open wordlist file");
    }
}
```

Or make sure the function has clearly separated return values for the string and the error status. One option would be to just return a `bool` to indicate the status, and pass a non-const reference to the string to be filled in with the word list:

```
bool load_file_to_string(const std::string &filename, std::string &string_from_file)
{
    ...
    if (error)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Or use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to combine the information into a single return value:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::string> load_file_to_string(const std::string &filename)
{
    ...
    if (error)
    {
        return {};
    }
    ...
    return string_from_file;
}
```

And this is how you use the latter:

```
auto dictionary = load_file_to_string("wordlist.txt");

if (!dictionary)
{
    std::cerr << "Please make sure that wordlist.txt is in the same directory as this program!\n";
    return 1;
}
...
secret_word = random_word_from_string(*dictionary);
```

## Use consistent code formatting

You are not very consistent in formatting your source code; sometimes there are spaces around operators and between `if` and `(`, sometimes not. I recommend always adding the spaces; it makes the code easier to read. This is a matter of taste, however it is always good to be at least consistent. You don't have to go over the code yourself and correct every small issue: there are code formatting tools that can do it for you. Perhaps the editor you are using to write the source code can already do it, otherwise there are [stand-alone code formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier) you can use.